# cx_Oracle in Python got Error ORA-01008: not all variables bound

Tags: python, database, oracle, bind, cx-oracle

I'm new using cx_oracle in python, I want to make update insert using Merge. But it return error:

ORA-01008: not all variables bound

I don't know why, but when I tried this query in oracle and it  success. Please help me

```
try_query= """merge into table_1 t
              USING (SELECT :a as COLA FROM dual) s
              ON (t.COLA = s.COLA)
              WHEN MATCHED THEN
                 UPDATE SET t.COLB = :b
              WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
                 INSERT (COLA,COLB)
                 VALUES (:a,:b)
              """
 data = [{'a':'aaa', 'b':'bbb'},{'a':'aaa222', 'b':'bbb222'}]
 cur.executemany(try_query,data)
```

Comment: I believe `data` is supposed to be a list of tuples, not a list of dicts.  See https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/batch_statement.html#batch-execution-of-sql

Comment: I just tried your code and it works for me! What versions of the Oracle Client and Database are you using? cx_Oracle? Note that there is a new driver (python-oracledb) that doesn't require the Oracle client, too. :-)